# How to create drop down like below image in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

is it possible to do? if possible then what element i should use for this. I searched so many time in google but not found functionality like this.

[image]

Comment: Try to make your spinner layout custom according to your task.

Comment: i have collapsing action bar above. in actionbar below icon this type of view should be open?Confuse what do in this? @Shane

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have a look on [How to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Share your code how you doing. And what is going with code.

Answer (score 2):

Just show and hide layout it will give you effect like drop down .

Answer (score 0):

We can do every thing we are androider's  look at this awesome example -http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

you can do like this also much easy -http://androidcodesnippetsblog.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-custom-dialog-with-popup.html